# Ant Builder for SASS in Zend Studio (Eclipse) "Is A Directory" Error

Tags: eclipse, windows, ant, sass, zend-studio

The build script I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="sass">
    <target name="sass">
        <apply dest="./sass" executable="sassy.bat">
            <srcfile />
            <targetfile />
            <mapper from="*.scss" to="*.css" type="glob"/>
            <fileset dir="./sass" includes="**/*.scss" />
        </apply>
    </target>
</project>
```

And it works great, with the condition that I have this external `sassy.bat` script on my `%%PATH%%`.

```
sass %1 %2
```

It compiles `sass/*.scss` files and puts the `*.css` in the same directory. However, if I don't use my `sassy.bat` and rather just use `sass.bat` it produces:

```
ruby.exe: Is a directory -- C:/project/sass (LoadError)
```

But in theory it should be running the same thing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem recently. The first step is to ensure that the builder is set to use a "Separate JRE" (Zend Studio's). The second step was to update my buildfile to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="sass">
    <target name="sass">
        <exec osfamily="windows" vmlauncher="false" executable="sass">
            <arg value="--update" />
            <arg value="scss/:css/" />
            <arg value="--style=compressed" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

The key was to set the `vmlauncher` attribute to `false` on Windows.